# "System.ServiceModel.Primitives"- assembly not found or dependecy not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I Have a project with a ASP.Net Web api. 
Since I added a Method to upload and download files a get a strange error.

```
The file or assembly "System.ServiceModel.Primitives" or a dependency thereof was not found. The signature with a strong name could not be verified. The assembly may have been modified or delayed, but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

If I get a knew copy of the repo the error doesn't occurs for about an hour. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Please check ASP.NET Web api project reference System.ServiceModel.Primitives dll.  please remove the reference then add and re-build solution and try.